# Format yourself for codegolf!

Tags: code-golf, quine

## Task

Your task is to write a program that, taking no input, outputs a string that represents a formatted codegolf answer of itself. The pattern is the following:

````
[Language name][1], n bytes
=
```
source code
```
  [1]: link-to-language
````

With the `language name` being the language that you wrote your program (as stated in your interpreter no abbreviations such as JavaScript => JS), `n` bytes being the byte-count of your language, `source code` being the source code of your program (hence the quine tag) and `link-to-language` being a link to a resource about your language - whichever your online interpreter points to. Note that this is a real quine challenge, so answers cannot read their own source code.

Comment: Are all of the spaces required?

Comment: Not gonna swing my dupe hammer due to the different formatting of the markdown but: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85024/code-golf-for-the-lazy) & [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98812/generate-a-markdown-template-for-your-post)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a Markdown Template for your Post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98812/generate-a-markdown-template-for-your-post)

Comment: Aside from being essentially duplicate, I don't find any novelty in this task over a regular quine, apart from the addition of some language-specific boilerplate.

Comment: What exactly is the link to the language?  The brief description really leaves a lot unanswered, especially since getting a shorter link is a very good way to decrease byte count.

Answer (score 3):

### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2), 102 bytes

````
_='## [Python 2][1], 102 bytes\n```\n_=%r;print _%%_\n```\n  [1]: https://docs.python.org/2';print _%_
````

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P95WXVlZIToAzFcwio02jNVRMDQwUkiqLEktjslLSEiIyYu3VS2yLijKzCtRiFdVjYeKKigAFVspZJSUFBRb6eun5CcX6xWAzdHLL0rXN1KHa4n//x8A "Python 2 – Try It Online"). Outputs exactly the source code of the post. Currently assumes that all of the spaces in the template are required.